# iPhone simulator theme

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, skin

Is it possible to change the iPhone Simulator skin to something more than just black package?:)

Comment: can you change theme in iphone device??

Comment: One use is for replacing the skin of the "iPhone (Retina)" skin -- which currently displays an iPad, for some reason -- with an iPhone skin, useful when creating demo videos at higher-than-standard resolution.

Comment: There is actually a very good reason for doing this. The default skin surrounds a black screen area with a black border, which is manifestly stupid for a debug / development environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into the iOS-Simulator package. In Contents/Ressources you will find frame.png which you can edit.

I have no idea why you would want to do that, though. :-)

Comment: I want to see how my icons look with different back colors. Who uses a black background?

Comment: One example of why I'd find that useful: I'm offsetting a button from the bottom of the device and the background on which the button is placed is black (also using react native not Storyboard/SwiftUI). So it's very difficult to see the space between the bottom of the screen and the bottom of the button without constantly changing that background colour in the CSS, especially on < iPhone 8s.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently yes (it was news to me until I searched). [See this link about making new graphics for the simulator](http://dribbble.com/shots/73904-White-iPhone-Simulator). Can't imagine why you'd want to though ...

Answer (score 0):

do yo want to change the wallpaper?? if yes then drag an image in simulator and it opens in the safari tap on it and alertsheet will appear choose to save this image... now go to your photos app and open that image. open the options (that's in lower left corner) and choose "Use as wallpaper"...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimalistic skin:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/115321914207029284487/posts/gcqBJej1g4R

It has very thin border, it is semitransparent and hasn't home button, instead use CMD+SHIFT+H shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Guess It's No Longer Exist For XCode 10 And Above, The Skin Now Is Located At:

Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Chrome/phone.simdevicechrome/Contents/Resources

There Is No One PNG File For The Skin Instead Several Pieces Of The Skin Puzzle Would Be Presented Into Multiple PDF Files (Buttons, Corners, ...etc.)

BTW The Skin Simulators For The Watch and The AppleTV is Using Same Path Except You Change The iPhoneOS.platform to AppleTVOS.platform Or WatchOS.platform

Comment: Please edit your answer and remove uppercase letters from words. Only the first word in a sentence should be capitalized. Using uppercase for all words makes the text unreadable.