# How can I set the device on the iOS Simulator as an iPhone 5 in Xcode 4.6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

How can I set the device on the iOS Simulator as an iPhone 5 in Xcode 4.6? I've been trying to change it via the Hardware->Device option but still to no avail. I really appreciate your help! Thanks.

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable, useful question. The downvotes that you received highlight a flaw in the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>In Xcode 4.6 this is not possible, you will just have to keep the iOS simulator open.
Apple did fix this issue in Xcode 5.</strike>

The iPhone 5 chrome (image that make the iOS simulator look like the iPhone5) will only been shown it there is enough space to present it. 
Other which it will just be a normal window, the working of the simulator are the same.

You can just select `device->iPhone(Retina 4-inch)` and use for example `Windows->50%` to make the simulator fit your screen.

Comment: I saw a video on youtube and this guy have it as an iPhone 5. Is it because of some compatible MacBooks and iMacs only? I'm currently using mid 2010 MacBook Pro i5.

Comment: If you mean that you want to have the iPhone chrome, this is only possible if the native resolution of your mac is high enough to show the chrome. Other which just select the `iPhone (Retina 4-inch)` and use the windows->scale to make it fit your screen.

Comment: Do you need to see the phone image? [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715528/iphone-simulator-theme) if so.

Comment: @rckoenes This is what what I'm talking about. I think the guy's using an iMac http://cl.ly/image/1Z37101Q1j05

Answer (score 1):

In 4.6, the iPhone 5 is the 4" iPhone option. This is current for Xcode 4.6.3.

[image]

Comment: Well I did chose the option but what I'm getting was this http://cl.ly/image/301l180V1M1b

Comment: That is correct. The 4-inch iPhone simulator does not have a border around it. It looks much like the iPad. Your image looks like it is just too large for your screen, try and zoom out a bit and it should all fit on your screen. Cmd + 2 or Cmd + 3.

Comment: I want it to be like this http://cl.ly/image/1Z37101Q1j05 and is it possible for me to get it like that?

Comment: No, Apple does not provide the border for the 4-inch simulator. Just like they don't provide it for the iPad. You will only see the phone border on the 3.5-inch simulator.

Answer (score 1):

first go to hardware then device then iphone (Retina 4 inch)
then u can go to window then scale if you want to change the size of simulator to look same like iphone 5